# Extract total hours that fall between two timestamps over multiple days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have predefined time segments that identify peak vs off-peak periods. An example would be:

7am-10am is **PEAK**

All time outside of this is **OFF_PEAK**

Within a transactional table, I have events which are logged and reported. The two main date fields we reference within this table are the date reported and the date completed. What I am looking to see is in the following example, is there a way to calculate the total # of **PEAK** hours impacted between the date reported and date completed?

**date_reported** : 2023-08-16 8:00AM

**date_completed** : 2023-08-19 2:00PM

In theory, I can do the manual calculation to see over the multiple days the cumulative peak hours impacted, but I am wondering how I might be able to use SQL to streamline and automate the check and calculation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to retag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: thanks i have updated it. sorry about that

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this it's really helpful to include example DDL/DML. I've inferred some from your description:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, StartDateTime DATETIME, EndDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (StartDateTime, EndDateTime) VALUES
('2023-01-01 00:00','2023-01-01 11:00'), ('2023-01-01 09:00','2023-01-01 13:00'), ('2024-01-01 09:00','2024-01-02 12:00');
```

If you don't have a calendar table, it's worth considering adding one if you have the ability to do so.

Without one you could use a `rCTE` to simulate one, which is what this example does (with the `Days` `CTE`).

This example uses hard coded start and end hours for the peak definition (7 and 10), but those are fairly straightforward to change.

From the data we can join to the calendar object for each day. We can then determine if we're on a different day than we started, or if the start time is part way through the window to determine todays start time. We can perform a similar operation for the end time. This gives us windowed start and end times for each day. It's then just a case of aggregating those values for each of the original rows.

```
;WITH Days AS (
SELECT CAST(MIN(StartDateTime) AS DATE) AS Day, MAX(EndDateTime) AS MxDay
  FROM @Table
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Day), MxDay
  FROM Days
 WHERE Day < MxDay
)

SELECT ID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, SUM(Hours) AS TotalPeakHours
  FROM (
        SELECT ID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDateTime) > 1 OR DATEPART(HOUR,StartDateTime) < 7 THEN '07:00' ELSE CAST(StartDateTime AS TIME) END,
                  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,Day,EndDateTime) > 0 OR DATEPART(HOUR,EndDateTime) > 10 THEN '10:00' ELSE CAST(EndDateTime AS TIME) END)/60.0 AS Hours
          FROM @Table t
            INNER JOIN Days d
              ON d.Day BETWEEN CAST(t.StartDateTime AS DATE) AND t.EndDateTime
       ) a
 GROUP BY ID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

| ID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | TotalPeakHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 3.000000 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 1.000000 |
| 3 | 2024-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2024-01-02 12:00:00.000 | 4.000000 |

Comment: thank you this is great! this gives me a good baseline to work off and make adjustments where necessary. appreciate your help.